# Is it okay to request a status completed tag?

Tags: support, tags, flags

I sometimes custom flag questions, asking a moderator to mark it *status completed*, because I believe the question served it's purpose, and most moderators mark my flag *helpful*, and actually add the requested tag.

But I'm not sure if that is a good thing to do.

In my experience, the tag is added mainly on MSE where people ask for new features to be added to the entire SE network, and this tag is added not just for *feature requests*, but for questions tagged *discussion*, *bug*, or *support* as well.

Currently the [tag wiki](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-completed/info) reads (emphasis mine):

> Indicates that a feature request has been implemented, a bug has been fixed, or **another type of request has been processed**.

What kind of questions deserve a *status completed* tag on ELU meta?

When should I request such a tag? Or should I never?

Comment: Mostly for things tagged [tag:feature-request] or [tag:bug]; that is, changes made by *developers* which effect the site as a whole. Think: the list of things you'd be interested in reading up on when you checked the tag "status completed". My take is individual flag actions are not wide-reaching enough to merit the tag.

Comment: As long as there is a *completed status* that can be reached that tag can be reasonably added—and requested.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a question about Meta itself, which belongs on ELU Meta _Meta_ ;-)